# Comparing Long object type with primitive int using ==

Tags: java, autoboxing

I have a method that returns a Long object datatype via invocation of: `resp.getResultCode()`. I want to compare it `HttpStatus.GONE.value()` which actually just returns a primitive int value of `410`. Would the Long unbox itself to properly compare with the int primitive?

```
if(resp.getResultCode() == HttpStatus.GONE.value()){
  // code inside..
}
```

Comment: Yes and the `int` will be promoted to a `long` value.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: That's an *answer*, not a comment. :-)

Comment: really? Why does it do that? that's surprising that the int would be promoted. I thought behind the scenes, the Long would be casted to an int.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the [JLS explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1)

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is [convertible (§5.1.8)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

and

> If the promoted type of the operands is `int` or `long`, then an integer equality test is performed.

So the `Long` is unboxed to `long`. And numeric promotion is applied to `int` to make it a `long`. Then they are compared.

Consider that case where `long` would be "demoted" to an `int`, you'd have cases like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long lvalue = 1234567891011L;
    int ivalue = 1912277059;
    System.out.println(lvalue == ivalue); // false
    System.out.println((int) lvalue == ivalue); // true, but shouldn't
}
```

Comment: The reason why that works is because the lower 32 bits are the same for both numbers. The demotion strips the upper bits of the long value; which is the reason why it should not be done.

Comment: Hi, where do I learn the knowledge for being able to understand what hfontanez said about bits and bytes? I'm not a CS guy, I studied music. I'm a musical programmer now. ;-)

Comment: @user836087 That's kind of a broad subject. Start at [wikipedia on binary numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number). Then review how primitive numerical types are represented in Java (if that's what you'll be using).